# My eclipse keeps crashing

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse x86 and jdk x86 on windows 7. Eclipse keeps crashing taking some work with it every time.

Information about eclipse from about screen:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Here's the screenshot of the text it displays upon crash

[image: screenshot]

How do I remedy the problem?

UPDATE: I re-installed everything, jre, jdk and eclipse. all 64 bit latest versions.

java info using System.getProperties();

---

java.runtime.name -> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment

sun.boot.library.path -> D:\java\jre\bin

java.vm.version -> 23.25-b01

java.vm.vendor -> Oracle Corporation

java.vendor.url -> http://java.oracle.com/

path.separator -> ;

java.vm.name -> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

file.encoding.pkg -> sun.io

user.country -> US

user.script ->

sun.java.launcher -> SUN_STANDARD

sun.os.patch.level -> Service Pack 1

java.vm.specification.name -> Java Virtual Machine Specification

user.dir -> D:\javathehutt\loop

java.runtime.version -> 1.7.0_25-b17

java.awt.graphicsenv -> sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment

java.endorsed.dirs -> D:\java\jre\lib\endorsed

os.arch -> amd64

java.io.tmpdir -> D:\TMP\

line.separator ->

java.vm.specification.vendor -> Oracle Corporation

user.variant ->

os.name -> Windows 7

sun.jnu.encoding -> Cp1252

java.library.path -> D:\java\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVtoolnix;D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;C:\phantomjs-1.8.1-windows;C:\Python27\Scripts;D:\pythonary\DIRECT_ACCESS;D:\gtk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;D:\java\jre\bin;D:\java\jdk\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;.

java.specification.name -> Java Platform API Specification

java.class.version -> 51.0

sun.management.compiler -> HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers

os.version -> 6.1

user.home -> C:\Users\aritra

user.timezone ->

java.awt.printerjob -> sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob

file.encoding -> Cp1252

java.specification.version -> 1.7

java.class.path -> D:\javathehutt\loop\bin

user.name -> aritra

java.vm.specification.version -> 1.7

sun.java.command -> loop

java.home -> D:\java\jre

sun.arch.data.model -> 64

user.language -> en

java.specification.vendor -> Oracle Corporation

awt.toolkit -> sun.awt.windows.WToolkit

java.vm.info -> mixed mode

java.version -> 1.7.0_25

java.ext.dirs -> D:\java\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext

sun.boot.class.path -> D:\java\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\java\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\java\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;D:\java\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\java\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\java\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\java\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\java\jre\classes

java.vendor -> Oracle Corporation

file.separator -> \

java.vendor.url.bug -> http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

sun.io.unicode.encoding -> UnicodeLittle

sun.cpu.endian -> little

sun.desktop -> windows

sun.cpu.isalist -> amd64

---

Eclipse info:
Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

It is still crashing with the same frequency. And it doesn't need me to do anything to crash. even if i just start eclipse and minimize it and keep it that way, it crashes in some time. What should I do? This is getting completely impossible to work with.
[image: screenie2]

As an extra question, I need eclipse for android work. Any other IDEs that I can replace eclipse with?

Comment: which version of eclipse do you have. if you dont have the latest version i would go for that

Comment: Make sure java is installed on your computer. You can remove eclipse and install again using [this guide](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/javaeclipseinstallation.html)

[Another good guide](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseJava_HowTo.html)

Comment: While you're at it, install the latest `JDK` too.

Comment: And make sure you match either a 32-bit Java and Eclipse with each other or use both 64-bit.

Comment: java and eclipse are both 32 bit.
Java version
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: other IDE options: Android Studio, IntelliJ

Comment: The Android Studio page says it's under development and features are not ready yet. Is is usable as of now?

Comment: Other IDE option Netbeans

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you have installed 64-bit JDK, but it seems you haven't cleaned previous Java path. Look at some of your path: `D:\java\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;D:\java\jre\bin;D:\java\jdk\bin;` It's so messy. Clean useless path, and set your latest Java path. In addition, you can use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) or [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for Eclipse replacement.

Comment: How do I get rid of those path entries like c:\windows\sun\java\bin?
My system and user path environment variable doesn't have that entry.. neither does it have any repetitions as the java System.getProperties() is showing. Where else are the paths stored?

Comment: did you set JAVA_HOME? or other variable?

Comment: I set JAVA_HOME to my jdk bin directory
also, I don't even have a c:\windows\sun directory. Its not mentioned in my environment variables, path or JAVA_HOME.. Where is java getting that location from? I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: try to set your latest Java path to the head of system environment variables.

Comment: I did that. Now there are no repeating entries in the environment variables and no double entries for java.. I cleaned it all up, eclipse still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are running eclipse with javaw.exe from windows\system32.  I find this a bad idea.

Open eclipse.ini and specify the VM from a JDK you want to use, in your case probably.

```
-vm
D:/Java/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/javaw.exe
```

Windows installs of Java are, IMHO, a bit of a mess. I would try to stick with a JDK you have installed yourself to a known directory.